# Telerik Kendo UI with MVVM

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm, kendo-listview

I have one Kendo UI Grid in my view page (MVVM Concept). Bind the data from view model. When I reduce the page size.

Kendo UI grid change to Kendo UI Listview. See this image:

[image: Grid view change to List view]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define one single DataSource for both Grid and ListView.

```
var ds = {
    data    : ...,
    pageSize: 10,
    schema  : {
        model: {
            fields: {
                Id       : { type: 'number' },
                FirstName: { type: 'string' },
                LastName : { type: 'string' },
                City     : { type: 'string' }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then define both a `DIV` for the Grid and for the ListView:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<div id="list"></div>
```

And initialize the Grid and the ListView:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    columns   :
    [
        { field: "FirstName", width: 90, title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName", width: 200, title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "City", width: 200 }
    ]
});

$("#list").kendoListView({
    dataSource: ds,
    template : $("#template").html()
});
```

Now, what you should do is display one or the other depending on the width:

```
// Display Grid (and hide ListView)
$("#grid").removeClass("ob-hidden");
$("#list").addClass("ob-hidden");

// Display ListView (and hide Grid)
$("#grid").addClass("ob-hidden");
$("#list").removeClass("ob-hidden");
```

Where CSS class `ob-hidden` is:

```
.ob-hidden {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Now, the only remaining question is invoke one or the other depending on the width. You can user jQuery `resize` event for detecting changes.

So, enclose both ListView and Grid in a `DIV` with `id` container:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <div id="list" class="ob-hidden"></div>
</div>
```

and define the `resize` handler as:

```
$("window").on("resize", function(e) {
    var width = $("#container").width();
    console.log(width);
    if (width < 300) {
        console.log("list");
        $("#grid").addClass("ob-hidden");
        $("#list").removeClass("ob-hidden");
    } else { 
        console.log("grid");
        $("#grid").removeClass("ob-hidden");
        $("#list").addClass("ob-hidden");
    }
});
```

**IMPORTANT**: Whatever you do for getting this same result, please, don't create and destroy the Grid and the ListView each time there is a `resize`. This a computationally expensive operation.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/JYXzJ/3/